# What does the array.pop()!(object) syntax in Codemirror do?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Codemirror 6's [documentation](https://codemirror.net/examples/collab/), and in the [code](https://github.com/codemirror/website/blob/master/site/examples/collab/worker.ts) line 41, ...

```js
while (pending.length) pending.pop()!(data.updates)
```

What does this syntax mean?
Seems to be typescript specific.
What would be the javascript equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, the `!` operator can also be used to assert that a value is non-nullable. This is called a non-null assertion operator, and it is used to tell the TypeScript compiler that a value is definitely not null or undefined. Check the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

The `pop()` method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

Since the return value is a function, well you can call it.